# WordPress - don't display certain posts within the main loop

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to get WordPress to not display certain posts but it still seems to display the posts that I'm telling it not to. I currently have this code:

```
<?php
    if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
    if (in_array($post->ID, $_SESSION['save_array_posts'])) continue;
?>
<div class="yl_bg_post main_content videos">
    <h2 class="title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <?php the_content('<p class="more">More></p>'); ?>
</div>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

And I'm trying to make WordPress not display certain posts that are stored within `$_SESSION['save_array_posts']`. The values are as follows:

```
array(5) { [0]=> int(190) [1]=> int(199) [2]=> int(63) [3]=> int(66) [4]=> int(68) }
```

WordPress seems to be looping through and still display them, I'm not quite sure why.

Comment: Not sure ,But I think you should set your post object ( `the_post()` ) AFTER your condition, and not BEFORE it ..  `if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts())` then `if (in_array...` and then setup object `the_post()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you have this problem but you could try to exclude posts in the query like this and see if that solves your problem:

```
$myPosts = new WP_Query(array('post__not_in' => $_SESSION['save_array_posts']));

while ($myPosts->have_posts()) : $myPosts->the_post(); ?>
```

Comment: You should check your $post->ID values if they are correct. I had similar problem once due to <?php the_ID(); ?> giving me wrong ID and I had to use wp_reset_query(); to fix it.